# Не видит компоненты cv2

Tags: python, opencv

Пытаюсь установить cv2 на Mac OS. Все установил, библиотека подключается, но вот составляющее библиотеки VS Code не видит. Что делать?

```
mymac:scripts totalboy$ pip install opencv-contrib-python
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-contrib-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (4.1.0.25)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from opencv-contrib-python) (1.16.4)
mymac:scripts totalboy$ pip install opencv-python
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (4.1.0.25)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.16.4)
mymac:scripts totalboy$
```

***Код***:

```
import cv2
import numpy

if __name__ == '__main__':
  image = cv2.imread('/Users/totalboy/Desktop/Projects/Bmp/Sample001/img001-00001.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) # Пишет: Module 'cv2' has no 'imread' memberpylint(no-member)
```

Comment: Вы, пожалуйста, точный текст ошибки воспроизведите

Comment: Добавил. Заметил особенность, скомпилировать я могу, и все работает отлично, но сам VS Code показывает ошибку...